# Execute php command using COM in windows

Tags: php, windows

I try to execute this in a php:

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg.exe -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="Microsoft® LifeCam Studio(TM)" full-video.webm';
$shell  = new \COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->Run($cmd, 0, false);
```

If I run the command in command line(cmd) it's working, but from php is not working. If I try to echo the command the result is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i video="Microsoft┬« LifeCam Studio(TM)" full-video.webm
```

I think is something about string enconding but I don't know.

Comment: I try this in windows 7 and is not working (in windows 8 is working prefectly)

Answer (score 0):

IT sounds like you actually want to use exec here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

The difference in output is because you're inputting utf-8 characters, and not telling your browser tht you want it to be interpreted as utf-8 on output.

Comment: I don't use a browser .. is command line. (cmd). I don't use exec because exec is blocking the process. (in linux I can use  > /dev/null 2>&1 & but in windows I have no idea).

Answer (score 0):

I need to use this command for make the shell to understand UTF-8.

```
chcp 65001
```

For make this permanent I need to do the following:

1. Start -> Run -> regedit
2. Go to [`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command
   Processor\Autorun`]
3. Change the value to `chcp 65001`

https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8

```
$shell  = new \COM("WScript.Shell");
$shell->Run(utf8_decode($cmd), 0, false);
```